# How to connect to router when DHPC is off?

Tags: router, internet

The router is ''Wind ZTE router". On official site says to type on browser 192.168.1.254 but this doesn't work. On ipconfig default gateway is blank. The router is connected only to PC via Ethernet. I am using windows 10. Is any way to connect to router?

Edit:The router is connected ONLY  to PC via Ethernet directly. DHPC is off i want to keep it off and to access it. The output of ipconfig:

```
Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::997:5726:cbe6:6f2e%2
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.111.46
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

Comment: How did you connect the router? Directly, through a stitch? What is the output of ipconfig? The default gateway doesn't really matter at this stage.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. There is a pending edit that I'm guessing is probably from you but under a different user name.  You can freely edit your own posts but for your protection, this must be done under the original user account.  It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer.  See [Merge my accounts](http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) to get your accounts merged, which will solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you I added more details. The router is connected to pc directly

Comment: Try?: 192.168.1.1. or 10.0.0.1. According to this manual: https://www.wind.gr/files/1/Wind_v2/statheri_epixeiriseis/devices/exoplismos2ZXV10-H108L-User-Manual-en.pdf. Default gateway should be the first one I gave you. (Step 4)

Comment: It is not working. It is  192.168.1.254  according to this https://www.wind.gr/en/wind/support/fixed-internet/parehomenos-exoplismos/anavathmisi-logismikou-router-zte/
and to this https://www.wind.gr/files/1/eksoplismostabs/ZTE_ZXHN_H108L_QSG.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, your router’s DHCP service is not enabled. Before you can connect to `192.168.1.254`, you first need to set up a static IP address on your PC’s network adapter.

To do this, right-click on the Start button, select “Network connections”. In the window that appears, bring up the properties of the network connection (via right-click). In the properties window, select “Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)” (do not remove the checkmark), then click “Properties”. Select “Use the following IP address” and enter the following values:

IP address: 192.168.1.10
Subnet: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.1.254
DNS: 192.168.1.254

Confirm all dialogs.

If, after setting this up, you still cannot connect to your router, it may be broken. First, however, try to reset it, the manual should have instructions on it.

Comment: It is not working.. Router is not broken because it connects me to internet with right static IP.

Comment: I have disabled DHPC because it creates problem to other PCs in accessing to internet

Comment: DHCP should never cause issues unless some (software) component is broken. However, what do you mean by “it connects me to internet with right static IP“? If you can’t connect to the router, you should not be in any position to determine this.

Comment: Well in my room I have an Ethernet cable  coming from server/switches. I can connect it directly to PC , use static IP and I would have access to Internet. But now I connect the Ethernet to router for 1) WiFi  2) Ethernet  ports for other PCs. If I have DHPC ON the others may connect to my router so they can't access to Internet and after  they have to use static IP.  My question is how to access router with DHPC OFF

Comment: It worked for IP: 192.168.1.200 Subnet: 255.255.255.0 Gateway: 192.168.1.254. The router have to be connected only to PC.

Comment: Perhaps you should connect your Internet uplink to the WAN port of the router, to allow for the router to perform its duty. That way, you can have DHCP on and connect multiple devices, too. You might have to change the local subnet so it doesn’t conflict with your uplink.

Comment: Yes. But I don't know how to set the local subnet to not conflict with uplink.

Answer (score 2):

It appears your computer needs to have a static IP in the same subnet as your router and/or your router hasn't got DHCP server enabled (hence why tor computer hasn't been given an IP and gateway automatically).

The IP you currently have (169.254.x.x) is known as an APIPA and is a special range of automatic addresses that computers can assign themselves if they can't communicate with a DHCP server.

If you set your computer to have a static IP of:

IP: 192.168.1.10
Subnet: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.1.254

This should, at least, be able to let you get to the router admin pages to properly configure it.

Alternatively (or additionally) you may want to hard reset the router so that it had the factory settings restored. This should re-enable and reset the (usually enabled) DHCP server and could fix your problem entirely).

Comment: This doesn't work.. :( .. Is any other static IP to try before I do hard reset?

Comment: It worked for IP: 192.168.1.200 Subnet: 255.255.255.0 Gateway: 192.168.1.254